# Question about flagging my own question

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging

I have just recently asked this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64902/supporting-enum-in-ef-5-with-net-4-0-visual-studio-2010) in Code Review, and an answer to my question was found in StackOverflow minutes later. Is it a good idea to flag my own question as a duplicate since the answer from that site was related to my question? I haven't flagged a question before so I did not want to do something without knowing if it is a good idea first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *could* flag your own question, but… is it really a duplicate?  The Stack Overflow answer may solve your main concern, but maybe there are other aspects about your code that could be improved.

I suggest that you use the Stack Overflow information to write an answer to your own question instead.